# Image rendering with Flying-Saucer/iText

Tags: itext, flying-saucer

I am trying to generate a pdf document from a Java String containing html
code. I am using "Freemarker" as a templating engine to generate the html
content and then "Flying-Saucer" to convert this generated html to pdf.
My problem is that images aren't rendered in the produced pdf. The exact
details about how I am generating are as follows:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.List;

import org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer;

import com.google.inject.Inject;
import com.google.inject.Singleton;
import com.lowagie.text.DocumentException;

import freemarker.template.Configuration;
import freemarker.template.DefaultObjectWrapper;
import freemarker.template.SimpleHash;
import freemarker.template.SimpleSequence;
import freemarker.template.Template;
import freemarker.template.TemplateException;

@Singleton
public class FlyingSaucerTaxInvoicePdfPrinter implements ITaxInvoicePdfPrinter {
    private final Configuration m_cfg;

    @Inject
    public FlyingSaucerTaxInvoicePdfPrinter() {
        // TODO: Following should be singletons and injected
        m_cfg = new Configuration();
        m_cfg.setObjectWrapper(new DefaultObjectWrapper());
        m_cfg.setClassForTemplateLoading(this.getClass(), "/");
    }

    private Template getTemplate() throws IOException {
        return m_cfg.getTemplate(PdfResources.TAX_INVOICE_TEMPLATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void printToPdf(TaxInvoiceUiPb taxInvoice, OutputStream pdfOutputStream) {
        OutputStream htmlOuputStream = null;
        try {
            htmlOuputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            printHtml(htmlOuputStream, taxInvoice);
            generatePDF(htmlOuputStream, pdfOutputStream);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new LoggedRuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            try {
                htmlOuputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new LoggedRuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }

    private void generatePDF(OutputStream htmlOuputStream, OutputStream pdfOutputStream)
                    throws DocumentException, IOException {
        try {
            ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer(30.666f, 20);
            String html = htmlOuputStream.toString();
            logHtml(html);
            renderer.setDocumentFromString(html);
            renderer.layout();
            renderer.createPDF(pdfOutputStream);
        } finally {
            pdfOutputStream.close();
        }
    }

// Some methods not shown as irrelevant
}
```

The generated html (showing only relevant section) is:

```
<body>
<div class="main" background="images/invoice-bg.jpg">
    <img src="images/invoice-bg.jpg"></img>
    <div class="header">
    <div class="logo"><img src="images/invoice-logo.jpg" alt="" border="0" /></div>
    <div class="heading">booking invoice</div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

This code runs as a War deployed on Tomcat. The location of the images in the War as output of 
tree command (run inside WEB-INF) is:

```
|-- classes
|   |-- com
|   |   `-- ilodge
|   |       `-- pmsServerWar
|   |           |-- PmsServerWarListener.class
|   |           `-- PmsServerWarServletModule.class
|   |-- images
|   |   |-- invoice-bg.jpg
|   |   |-- rupees-icon-total.png
|   |   |-- thank-you.jpg
|   |   |-- total-bold-rupee.png
|   |   `-- ul-bor.jpg
|   |-- taxInvoice.css
|   |-- taxInvoiceFooter.ftl
|   |-- taxInvoice.ftl
|   `-- test.ftl
|-- lib
|   |-- addressServer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
|   |-- addressUiProtobuf-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
|   `-- xml-apis-1.3.03.jar
`-- web.xml
```

I have truncated the output for brevity. Please help.

Thanks and regards,
Rohit

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the baseUrl parameter.

I had the same problem - I'm passing in html and wasn't getting images (or css for that matter) in the pdf. I used the exact same thing as you:

```
renderer.setDocumentFromString(html);
```

That method can also take a base url parameter:

```
renderer.setDocumentFromString(content, baseUrl)
```

Where baseUrl = the root folder (in my case it's a web application, so it was 'http ://server:port/app'). It seems to work like a base href - relative paths build on the baseUrl. Once I added that in, blammo - images and css.

Answer (score 1):

A possible problem can be that you use relative URL's in the html code. Try to use an absolute URL, instead of relative.